# Specific xpath is not working in puppeteer js

Tags: puppeteer

I have a specific xpath that's not working.  I'm waiting for the XPath to appear but for some reason I still can't get it.

Here is the xpath:
I'm using: `'//*[@id="settings"]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/form/div[4]/div/div[2]/button[contains(text(), "Save")]'`

To confirm that this xpath is in the page I go to my console and evaluate it.

```
$x('//*[@id="settings"]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/form/div[4]/div/div[2]/button[contains(text(), "Save")]')
```

Then I get this:

```
[button.ml3-sm.mb1-sm.css-17hmqcn.ex41m6f0.primary]
0: button.ml3-sm.mb1-sm.css-17hmqcn.ex41m6f0.primary
```

My code is as follows:

```
  await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="settings"]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/form/div[4]/div/div[2]/button[contains(text(), "Save")]');
  const [setting] = await page.$x('//*[@id="settings"]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/form/div[4]/div/div[2]/button[contains(text(), "Save")]');
  if(setting) setting.click();
```

I await for the element.  I can visually see it on the page and also like i mentioned above I can evaluate it but the click never fires.
I've also tried this:

```
setting[0].click().
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well from within the browser console: from inspector, right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Comment: Fixed @GillesQuenot

Comment: If it is a public webpage you are trying to interact with can you share its url? I just see you are having a hard time with this specific element. I am sure there is a solution out there ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your selector is good, especially if you've been able to validate it through Chrome DevTools console.

I think you just need to `await` the click:

```js
if(setting) await setting.click();
```

OR (without destructuring use the 1st index on `[0]`)

```js
await setting[0].click();
```